# How to have Nameserver records for a custom Nameserver, with said records on those nameservers

Tags: dns, nameserver, dns-servers

I've recently started hosting my own dns, I like being able to brand it on my own. The way I'm doing it right now, I still have the domain the nameservers are on hosted on external dns, so I can point the records where they should go.

I have 4 nameservers:

- (primary) ns1 - Dallas, Texas
- (slave)  ns2 - Toronto, Ontario
- (slave)  ns3 - London, United Kingdom
- (slave)  ns4 - Tokyo, Japan

Each of them has an A & AAAA record on the domain **example.com**, `ns1.example.com`, `ns2.example.com`, etc. I want to have example.com's DNS hosted on those nameservers, but I can't since I have to have those records there. The actual domain is at 101 Domain (not my personal choice, had to for a `.bot` domain). Anyone know of a way I can have my records *exist*, and also host my dns on my custom servers?

Comment: Why do you want to brand it?   Only a few of the most technical end users ever would see your NameServer records.  For many of those users, it is more trustworthy to use a well known DNS host.  Self-hosted DNS has a really bad reputation.